# How to hide this specific image for mobile on Windows Phone?

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile

I can't figure out how to hide the logo image for mobile devices which is used for the background for my Age Verification popup. Here is the site with the pop-up logo in question: http://rocketcannabis.com/?itro_preview=yes

I got pretty close with the following code, but don't know how to isolate the image, I could only hide the whole pop with the #itro_popup class, I want just the image to hide on mobile, not the whole pop-up:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
#itro_popup {
 display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `background-image: none`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 #itro_popup {
   background-image: none;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding `!important` to `display:`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
#itro_popup {
  background-image: none !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks guys, it was a combo of the two.. Myco you just forgot the background-image part... but the !important is what did the trick. so here's what worked:  }
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
 #itro_popup {
   background-image: none !important;
 }

Comment: okay thanks i will change my post.. into background-image: none !important, i hope it will help to others.. but if work for you don't forget to click vote. if really help for you..